# executing jar with arguments Hide text of some arguments

Tags: cmd, jar, executable-jar

I have a jar file that accepts the arguments, one of the argument is a password, is there a way to mask password when executing jar in CMD? maybe in Java code argument can be masked or I don't reveal sensitive information? something like there is in Linux command when typing the password noting is shown in terminal?

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
   String username = args[0]; //=="user"
   String password = args[1]; //=="pass"
}
```

and in cmd executing it

```
java -jar jarFile.jar username password
```

is there a way to hide that password in the second argument?